# Unity point clone to specific GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, direction

I want to have clones of a certian gameobject face the direction of the player at an angle, for example, if there were enemy clones with guns I would want the guns to face the players position. Any ideas how to do?

[image: inspector]

This is even harder to achieve because since it's a clone you cannot access other GameObjects.

#### Script:

```
public class GunProperties : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform target;
    void Update() 
    {
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: A clone doesn’t stop you doing anything

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the clones with some values when you instantiate it.

#### Example:

In this case I have a GameManager that keeps track on the player, and passes the reference over when an enemy is spawned.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform player;
    public Enemy enemyPrefab;

    void SpawnEnemy() {
        var enemy = Instantiate<Enemy>(enemyPrefab);
        enemy.Init(player)
    }
}

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    
    private GunProperties gun;
    
    public void Init(Transform target) {
        gun.target = target;
    }
}
```

You could also reverse it by making the GameManager a singleton and having the enemies find the player on awake by using **GameManager.Instance.player**